# Add matches from array to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, model-view-controller, ienumerable

I am currently having problems with my search results. The user can search for different items such as categories, types, price etc. The problem is that my returned list is not returning the items when I've selected multiple categories. 
I've a view that is submitting a GET request through ajax and the data is correctly loaded into the mvc action method which is passed to my method that is returning the matching results. The categories are sent as an array into the viewModel.

```
public IEnumerable<AdSearchViewModel> GetItemsFromSearch(AdSearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    var result = from a in _dbContext.AdTable
                    select new AdSearchViewModel
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        CategoryId = a.CategoryId,
                        TypeId = a.TypeId,
                        Brand = a.Brand,
                        Price = a.Price,
                        Description = a.Description
                    };
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        if (viewModel.Id.HasValue)
            result = result.Where(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id);
        if (viewModel.SelectedCategory != null && viewModel.SelectedCategory.Length > 0)
        {
            result = viewModel.SelectedCategory.Aggregate(result, (current, item) => current.Where(x => x.CategoryId == item));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Name))
            result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(viewModel.Name));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Brand))
            result = result.Where(x => x.Brand.Contains(viewModel.Brand));
        if (viewModel.PriceFrom.HasValue)
            result = result.Where(x => x.Price >= viewModel.PriceFrom);
        if (viewModel.PriceFrom.HasValue)
            result = result.Where(x => x.Price <= viewModel.PriceTo);
    }
    //TODO: return newest 
    return result;
}
```

The correct items are loaded when I only click one category. I tried with a foreach with the array (still no luck) but Visual Studio suggested the aggregated function which called the error ({"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}).

> Getting the DeclaringMethod property on a type whose  IsGenericParameter property is false throws an  InvalidOperationException. - MSND Documentation

What is the correct way to add the matching result with the selected categories?

I found the solution!
This worked for me:

`result = result.Where(x => viewModel.SelectedCategory.Any(y => y == x.CategoryId));`

Answer (score 1):

Chnage return value of your action to:

```
public IEnumerable<AdSearchViewModel> GetItemsFromSearch(AdSearchViewModel viewModel)
```